# Send response body back from Salesforce API

Tags: rest-api, api, apexrest, rest-service

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/UploadDoc/*')
global class CreateNewDoc{

@HttpPost     
 global static void doPost() {
 RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
 RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
 String jsonBody = req.requestBody.toString();
 System.debug('attachmentJSON===='+jsonBody);
 try{ 
    res.responseBody(Blob.valueOf(MyClass.uploadBody(jsonBody)));   
 }
     catch(Exception e){
     System.debug('exception===='+e);
     }
  }
}
```

I will be hitting the rest url from 3rd party resourse(tring to test via workbench). Here MyClass.uploadBody creates a document and returns the id.

Now I want to return set the Id and return it to the 3rd party as a response body.

I am trying to use the below code which is not working ad throwing me an error

```
    res.responseBody(Blob.valueOf(MyClass.uploadBody(jsonBody)));
```

**Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void responseBody(Blob) from the type System.RestResponse**

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing

```
res.responseBody(Blob.valueOf(MyClass.uploadBody(jsonBody)));
```

to

```
res.responseBody = blob.valueOf(MyClass.uploadBody(jsonBody));
```

Answer (score 0):

res.responseBody= Blob.valueOf(MyClass.uploadBody(jsonBody));

Assign the value. response body is not a method. It's an attribute.